# RESTFul API using Java: Where I can find sample RESTFul API services for testing purpose

Tags: java, api

I wanna build sample framework for POC using Rest Assured Java to test REST APIs. Where I can find sample REST APIs for testing purpose.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Have you tried googling this? As is, this question can receive many possible equally valid answers and as such is one of the [types of question to avoid asking on the site](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Hi Tried and got few valid sample websites, but those provide GET request. I wanna check POST request as well to complete by poc.

Comment: You want to put as much detail in your question as possible (please read [ask]). Otherwise, GIGO. Think about that in future questions. Glad to have answered, though.

Comment: Rather than "where can I find x.", which are a class of off topic shopping questions, try asking how to solve a specific problem. Show where you are stuck and having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Related question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17919/json-test-server-with-regularly-updating-data) , although it might be `get` only, but it references other stuff which might help, and will also give you an idea of what to Google for.

IGTFY:   https://reqres.in/ is what you want.

> **Fake data**
>
> No more tedious sample data creation, we've got it covered.
>
> **Real responses**
>
> Develop with real response codes. GET, POST, PUT & DELETE supported.
>
> **Always-on**
>
> 24/7 **free** access in your development phases. Go nuts.

Btw, for testing APIs, be aware of [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

(also, Fiddler2 is helpful, but I dropped it when I moved to Postman; YKMV [Your Kilometrage May Vary]).

Comment: Possibly also https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/